# When using "win_command: mklink softlinkfile destfile" can not locate mklink.exe\"

Tags: command, ansible, mklink

I'm using ansible to manage several windows hosts on the cloud, I need to create a log file and link it to another file, so I use the follow playbook

```
- name: init the directory structure of windows
  hosts: '{{windows_hosts}}'
  tasks:
   - name: create log file and link it to log directory
     win_command: mklink log D:\prod\log
     args:
        chdir: D:\prod\project
```

when running this playbook, the hosts can be found successfully, but I got the following error report

```
> TASK [Gathering Facts]
> ********* ok: [111.111.2.40]
> 
> TASK [create log file and link it to log directory]
> ********* fatal: [111.231.76.40]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "mklink log
> D:\\prod\\log", "msg": "Exception calling \"SearchPath\" with \"1\"
> argument(s): \"Could not locate the following executable
> mklink.exe\"", "rc": 2}
```

and I tryed this command on the remote host in the same directory, it can be execute successfully. I don't know what to do......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

win_command is for running executables directly. Hence the user's environment isn't applied and you aren't running inside a dos box or powershell window

so 'mklink' isn't actually an executable - its a built-in feature of the cmd.exe program.  So to run mklink via win_command, you'd have to run the cmd.exe program and pass it an argument to tell it do what 'mklink' does, like this:

`win_command: cmd.exe /k mklink log D:\prod\log`

Comment: Thank you!  You answer perfectly solved my problem!  but I don't understand the function of  "/k", I tried to omit it, there was no error, but the no softlink is generated!

Comment: And can you help me on another similar problem? thank you very much!!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317443/ansible-win-copy-does-not-work-error-src-file-does-not-exist

Comment: you can take a look at cmd.exe /? for all the options.

Comment: @JuliaChen below is some of the manual
---
Starts a new instance of the Windows command interpreter

CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
    [[/S] [/C | /K] string]

/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
/S      Modifies the treatment of string after /C or /K (see below)
/Q      Turns echo off
/D      Disable execution of AutoRun commands from registry (see below)
---
... this is the max I am allowed to post. More options under "cmd.exe /?"

Answer (score 2):

Do the following way:

```
---
  - name: Run Windows Command
    hosts: windows
    gather_facts: False

    tasks: 
      - name: win command
        win_shell: cmd /k mklink log D:\prod\log
        args: 
          chdir: D:\prod\project
```