# ansible win_copy does not work "error: src file does not exist"

Tags: ansible

I try to use the following playbook to copy a mp3 file to D:\

```
- name: copy file
  hosts: windows
  - name: copy file to D:
    win_copy:
      src: X:\assets\audio.mp3
      dest: D:\template\
      remote_src: yes
```

but I get the following error message:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts]**********************************************
ok: [111.111.23.40]

TASK [copy file to D:] ********************************
fatal: [111.231.76.40]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "dest": 
"D:\\template\\", "msg": "Cannot copy src file: 'X:\\assets\\audio.mp3' 
as it does not exist", "src": "X:\\assets\\audio.mp3"}
```

I'm sure file `X:\\assets\\audio.mp3` exists, and `X:\` is a shared file of the linux control machine.

[you can see the src file in this directory structor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSwPT.jpg)
When I upload the windows machine and run

```
copy X:\assets\audio.mp3 D:\template\
```

in the cmd.exe, the audio.mp3 can successfully be copied! I also tried to copy another file on the windows machine, for example:

```
- name: copy file
  hosts: windows
  - name: copy template to D:
    win_copy:
      src: D:\document\test.txt
      dest: D:\template\
      remote_src: yes
```

this task can be run successfully!

And I tried other way, for example

```
- name: copy file
  hosts: windows
  - name: copy template to D:
    win_command: cmd.exe /k copy X:\assets\audio.mp3 D:\template\
```

there is no error, but I can't get the copied file! This really distract me!

Comment: check your file permission. if your mp3 file and parent directory have the correct permission.

Also can you please run ansible in verbose mode with -vvvv command

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
remote_src: true
```

This line is checking for the file on your client machine .

Comment: Set to false to work

Answer (score 0):

Either you create a powershell script which does the mapping and copying. And then you use ansible to perform your task using thr powershell script.

The other way (Here assuming that both source and destination servers are on same domain )

```
     - name: copy files
       win_copy:
          src: \\domain_server\c$\somefile.txt
          dest: c:\Dir\somefile.txt
          remote_src: true
```

`

Comment: I tried your method, there is no error,                                                                 TASK [create a mapped drive under F] ********************** ok: [111.111.20.40]

TASK [copy file] *********************************************changed: [111.111.20.40] but it also no work! the copy command didn't successfully excuted

Comment: This might be tricky!! What authentication method you are using?